# Output file printing

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

Writing a clustering program to place data points in nearest cluster. I would like the program to print the output file to look like this. The first half of the code places the points in the correct cluster.

```
Point 1.8 in cluster 0
Point 4.5 in cluster 1
Point 1.1 in cluster 2
Point 2.1 in cluster 0
Point 9.8 in cluster 4
```

the this is the main part of the code

```
  itr_times = 0
   while True:
      itr_times += 1
      clusters = assign_to_clusters(input_points, centroids)

print("Iteration " + str(itr_times))
for index in range(total_clusters):
    print(index, clusters[index])
print("")

centroids_updated = update_location(clusters, centroids)
   if not centroids_updated:
      break

with open(output_file, 'w') as output_file:
   for p in input_points:
    output_file.write(float("Point {} in cluster {}\n".format(
        p, points_cluster_index_dict[p])))
   output_file.close
```

Comment: And what problem do you encounter?

Comment: this is the error message I receive                                                
    [input_points = [float(line.strip()) for line in input_file]
    ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Point 1.8 in cluster 0']